# How to render a time-of-day string like '16:42' with a site's chosen time format?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, localization, date-time

I have a need to display a time-of-day value in a site's chosen time format.

For example I have `16:42:18` and want to display it as `4:42 PM` if the `time_format` option is `g:i A`, or `16:42:18` if the `time_format` is `H:i:s`.

I need this to render data captured by HTML5's [<input type="time">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) form field.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is using [wp_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_date/) in a peculiar way, giving it the time of day in seconds (as if it were `1970-01-01 16:42:18`), then asking for it to be formatted in UTC.

```php
$time = '16:42:18';
if ( preg_match( '/^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/', $time ) ) {    //validate the $time
  $ts =  intval( substr( $time, 0, 2 ) ) * 3600;
  $ts += intval( substr( $time, 3, 2 ) ) * 60;
  $ts += intval( substr( $time, 7, 2 ) );
  if ( $ts >= 0 && $ts < 86400 ) {
     $time = wp_date( get_option( 'time_format' ), $ts, 'UTC' );
  }
}
```